# Add to lightbox not working in dynamically loaded content (AJAX PHP)

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax

Hi I have some code that adds models to a lightbox, this code is working as expected on static pages like so: http://pha-group.com/models/females/

```
    $scope.add = function(permalink, post_id)
{
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        var selectedOption = localStorage.lightbox_list;
    } else {
        var selectedOption = null;
    }


    $http.get('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=lightbox_add_talent_ajax&permalink='+permalink+'&list='+selectedOption).success(function(data) {


        var pop_up_talent = data.attachments;

        if(pop_up_talent)
        {
            var pop_up_talent = $.map(pop_up_talent, function(value, index) {
                return [value];
            });

            $scope.lightbox_popup = pop_up_talent.slice(0, 3);

        }


        $scope.lightbox = data.attachments;

        updateBubbleCounter();

        loading(data.last_insert, 'add');

    }).error(function(){
        console.log('unable to add to lightbox list');
    });

};
```

However on this page: http://raretalent.pha-group.com/ I load the talent in dynamically with this code..

```
        function get_posts($params) {

        $container = $('#container-async');
        $content   = $container.find('.content-ajax');
        $status    = $container.find('.status');

        $status.text('Fetching talent...');

        $.ajax({
                    //url: bobz.ajax_url,
                    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                    data: {
                        action: 'do_filter_posts',
                    nonce: bobz.nonce,
                    params: $params
                    },
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {

                        if (data.status === 200) {
                            $content.html(data.content);
                        }
                        else if (data.status === 201) {
                            $content.html(data.message);    
                        }
                        else {
                            $status.html(data.message);
                        }

                        script_cycle();
                 },
                 error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                $status.html(textStatus);

                /*console.log(MLHttpRequest);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);*/
                 },
            complete: function(data, textStatus) {

                msg = textStatus;

                if (textStatus === 'success') {
                    msg = data.responseJSON.found;
                }

                // $status.text('Posts found: ' + msg);
                $status.text('');

                /*console.log(data);
                console.log(textStatus);*/
            }
        });
    }
```

And when I click to add to lightbox on this page http://raretalent.pha-group.com/, nothing happens!! I know that I need to load the lightbox function on the successful AJAX call but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

By loading content via ajax you add them to the page after your function for the plus icon is completed. So there is not event handler applied to the dynamic elements.
I am not an angular export but maybe this helps you out.

https://medium.com/@jsoo1/dynamic-content-with-angularjs-7a88b931c136

Comment: Hi, thanks, could I simply call/load the script in the ajax success of the dynamically loaded content?

Comment: "scope.add" is the function to retrieve more models? Than this should be called again on succes of the loading. Maybe event handler that have been already set before should be removed to prevent doubling the event. But as i said, i am not an angular expert. There is probably a more elegant way to do this in the framework.